# Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is invalid: self intersects

Tags: postgis, polygon, geometry, sfcgal

I am trying to calculate the volume of an object with geometry type --PolyhedralSurface.

`ST_MakeSolid(geom)` is valid, while `ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(geom))` is invalid for the following reasons:

> ERROR:  Solid is invalid : PolyhedralSurface (shell) 0 is invalid:
>   self intersects : SOLID((((1330234219957071/8796093022208
>   -4773528275075025/140737488355328 5317672848006863/140737488355328,5320936439706973/35184372088832
>   -1193384456837643/35184372088832 5317672848006863/140737488355328,5320936439706973/35184372088832
>   -1193384456837643/35184372088832 1449419028924835/35184372088832,1330234219957071/8796093022208
>   -4773528275075025/140737488355328 5317672848006863/140737488355328)),((5320936439706973/35184372088832
>   -1193384456837643/35184372088832 5317672848006863/140737488355328,1330234219957071/8796093022208
>   -4773528275075025/140737488355328 5317672848006863/140737488355328,5320936440094001/35184372088832
>   -4773537827491309/140737488355328 5317672848006863/140737488355328,5320936439706973/35184372088832
>   -1193384456837643/35184372088832 5317672848006863/140737488355328)),...

Comment: Could you possibly edit the querstion with the original geometry and not just the error?